# What is the SQL or Spark code to find customers who made 3 or more orders within 60 days?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Find if a customer has made 3 or more orders within 60 days at any time in the past.
Kindly help with the SQL or spark code for this

Hi All,

We are trying to find a way to identify all customers that have purchased in bulk. For example, if a customer has made 3 or more orders within 60 days will be marked as bulk for only those orders. Below is the sample data with expected outcome. enter image description here
Sample data with expected output

The table has customer name, order date and order id.
Kindly help with the SQL and spark code for this

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table structure it's not possible to provide correct answer. But you need to write something like this:

For example if your orders table consists of customername,orderdate then the query will be

```
select customername,count(*) OrderQuantity from orders 
where orderdate>=dateadd(day,-60,getdate())
group by customername 
having count(*)>=3
```

Comment: This will not work. I dont want to know orders place in last 60 days. We need orders placed within 60 days at any point in time in the past by the same customer

Comment: This query will fetch those customers who place 3 or more orders in last 60 days.